# Python: Deleting records matching the list ( $in equivalent for Models ? )

Tags: python-2.7, mongoengine

Is there any query for mongoengine models that will delete all the records which matches list elements.

I have Model called **brands** and I am using pymongo query for deleting all the records that matches elements present inside **brandIDArray**, its array of Id.

*PyMongo Way  :* 
**db.brands.remove({ "_id": { "$in":  brandIDArray} })**

this is just a temporary fix, I want to use model here like 
brands.delete(brandIDArray)

*Mongoengine Way ??*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `in` [query operator](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)

An example can be found here: [find all pages Bob authored](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#one-to-many-with-listfields)

You can provide either a list of ObjectId's or a list of model instances.

Comment: BrandsModel.objects.get(pk__in=brandsIDArray).delete()

throwing error : 


MultipleObjectsReturned....

2 items returned, instead of 1 .....

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned....

Comment: Solved !!   

BrandsModel.objects(pk__in=brandsIDArray).delete()